# Tabindex Focus Styles

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I have made a `div` tabbable with the `tabindex` attribute to make hidden content accessible.

Currently when clicked with the mouse the `div` gets browser `:focus` styling.

Is there a way to have that tabbable element to only have focus styling *when accessed via the keyboard*? An anchor element has this by default.

- `Div` with `tabindex='0'` gets browser focus styles on mouse and keyboard
  interaction
- Anchor gets browser focus styles on keyboard interaction
  only

I would like the div to emulate the anchor. Making it an anchor is not an option though unfortunately.

Any help would be great, I'm genuinely at a loss.

Edit -> Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/LvXyL/2/

Comment: FWIW: It looks like the behavior you are describing is actually browser-dependent: in Chrome, div gets the focus style on mouse/keyboard but anchor only on keyboard as you describe; but in IE, *both* get the focus rectangle on either mouse or keyboard; meanwhile in Firefox, neither get the focus outline *until* the keyboard is used in that frame, and after that both get the focus outline for both mouse or keyboard!

Answer (score 8):

Sure just add the :focus pseudo-class to the div, and style. I recommend using outline vs border. I updated the fiddle.

```
div:focus {outline: blue solid 2px;}
```

Kub suggested a JS solution, but why use js if you don't actually need to?

Comment: Because, he want set focus only by keyboard not by mouse.

Comment: and what happens if said user has JS off? This approach covers mouse and keyboard.

Comment: I'd prefer to retain default browser focus styling, and for the focus to only display for keyboard navigation.

Answer (score 4):

I've had great success using javascript to add/remove a class to the body that indicates if the user is using a mouse or a keyboard. Use those classes to style your focus states as you desire.

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
  document.body.classList.add("using-mouse")
  document.body.classList.remove("using-keyboard")
})

document.addEventListener("keydown", () => {
  document.body.classList.add("using-keyboard")
  document.body.classList.remove("using-mouse")
})
```

The in the css you can do something like:

```
.using-mouse :focus {
  outline: none;
}

.using-keyboard :focus {
  outline: auto 5px blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to **don't be specific on tags like `div`, `p`, `span`**

let's write one common selector to achieve this functionality for all the elements.

```
*:focus {
   outline: blue solid 2px;
}
```

If you want to be specific then I would suggest this one.

```
*[tabindex]:focus {
    outline: 2px green solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the `focus-visible` css selector to apply different styles for keyboard focus and mouse click.

The way I implemented it is like this:

```
.your-element's-classname:focus:not(:focus-visible) {  outline: none; }
```

When you focus it with the keyboard you will see the browser's focus styling or the custom styling you have made for your element, and when you click it you will see no styling because I have applied `outline:none` which removes the outline created by the browser's focus styling.

You can find more information in [Mozilla's `focus-visible` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible) and [Chromium's browser focus article](https://blog.chromium.org/2020/09/giving-users-and-developers-more.html#:%7E:text=Highlight%20come%20in.-,%3Afocus%2Dvisible,with%20a%20mouse%20does%20not.).

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking to override the **tabindex focus style** and preserve the original functionality of tabindex ie. show outline only when tab key is pressed and not on mouse click like if

```
:focus {
    outline: 2px solid lime;
}
```

is used it will show outline on every element that is getting focus, but I found out that if I use

**Change Tabindex Style - for all elements:**

```
 :focus-visible {
    outline: 2px solid lime;
}
```

this will override the outline style of the tabindex on focus and preserve the tab outline functionality but with the new outline style.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible

Answer (score -1):

If you can use javascript, try use `onclick` attribute.

`onclick="this.blur()"` for lost focus

`onclick="this.focus()"` for set focus

Example where `DIV` on click lost focus and `A` is set focus http://jsfiddle.net/LvXyL/6/

Disadvantage is visible focus style if you hold mouse key for a longer time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is quite close but the focus remains on mouse down and when clicking and dragging off the element.

Comment: Using this.blur() is not recommended, as it will interfere with correct keyboard usage. Clicking on a tabbable div *should* set the focus there, but using this.blur() prevents this.